# How to close tinymce inline popup

Tags: plugin-development, tinymce, plugin-tinymce

I have been looking around, but am unable to close the popup programmatically.

The following code does not seem to work.

```
tinyMCEPopup.close()
TypeError: Cannot read property 'windowManager' of undefined
```

note: I am running this in chrome console, it might running in the scope of window.top

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

The window which was opened had to call the tinyMCEPopup.close() in its own scope. Which also meant I had to include the tiny_mce_popup.js script as well.